# IBM Lotus Domino Howto Move Archive to Other Partition

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, email-server, ibm-domino

I have **Lotus Domino 8.5.3 FP6** installed on **Windows 2008 R2** with following folders structure.

```
D:\LOTUS\DOMINO\DATA\MAIL   > 500 GB , users inbox
D:\LOTUS\DOMINO\DATA\MAIL\ARCHIVE > 1000 GB , users archived mails
```

**Archiving** policy is enabled/done on the server end on a weekly basis, which moves 1 year old email from the inbox to archive.

Space is getting low in **D:** partition therefore I have added new drive (**E:**) and wants to **move** user email **Archives** to new partition **E:\ARCHIVE**

1. What is the best method to move Archives to new partition?
2. What modifications would be required in configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

You can play with folder links on OS level, or use Domino to do all work for you.

Check this out:
https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Using_Directory_Links_to_access_data_outside_the_NotesData_path

In brief:

- Quit Domino
- Move ARCHIVE folder to new disk/partition, create ARCHIVE.DIR file in MAIL folder...
- Stard Domino

Comment: What If I dont want to shutdown the domino server as it runs 24x7 and accessed by remote users as well in different time zone. Using Domino Admin Client MOVE function is a better way to go ?  
  If i use MOVE function from domino client ,   I have to change the folders settings in Archive policy setting too?   what is better?  
  .DIR approach seems very simple to me ,   Hopefully it dont have any drawbacks, does it ?:)

Comment: Move will not be happy if users are accessing data also...
.DIR we used many times since old versions, had no issue with it - it's quite simple solution and concept.
And yes, you have to change policies if "path" changes - with DIR - path is "same" for Domino and users.

Comment: Ok I have **Symantec backup exec** Server on another System (same network) which takes **Domino** backup as well via network.    Will Backup Exec automatically redirected to *e:\archive* via **.dir** file ? **OR** I have to add the new *e:\archive_new* folder manually in backup exec?

Comment: I'm not sure, but, if Symantec is using NRPC and job is defined as Domino data paths, everything should be fine, but, you should check backup after this kind of change.

Comment: Ok I have replica serve as well for this domino server. will this movement on primary server will effect any thing on replica?

Comment: No. Replica works only according to ReplicaID - filepath is not important.